# Xamarin Forms: UI is not updated from an event

Tags: c#, multithreading, xamarin, asynchronous, xamarin.forms

I have some issues updating the ui. This is the code:

```
 async Task StartListening()
    {
        try
        {
            if (CrossGeolocator.Current.IsListening)
                return;

            await CrossGeolocator.Current.StartListeningAsync(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500), _locationTrackingFrequency, true, new ListenerSettings
            {
                ActivityType = ActivityType.AutomotiveNavigation,
                AllowBackgroundUpdates = true,
                DeferLocationUpdates = true,
                DeferralDistanceMeters = 1,
                DeferralTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
                ListenForSignificantChanges = false,
                PauseLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
            });
            CrossGeolocator.Current.PositionChanged += CrossGeolocator_Current_PositionChanged;

        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            await LogEvents.LogEvent(exception.ToString(), 15);
        }
    }
```

StartListening method is executed when i press a button.
CrossGeolocator_Current_PositionChanged is executed when gps location is changed

```
public async void CrossGeolocator_Current_PositionChanged(object sender, PositionEventArgs e)
    {
       Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => { IsBusy = true; });
    }
```

The Ui is updated when i am still on that page so it means the above implementation works. However when i change page and i come again at this page the ui is not updated even though the command is executed(i can see it from debug).
The Navigation i do is View Model to View Model

```
private void RedirectToPage(MainMenuItem menuItem)
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async() =>
        {
            var type = menuItem?.ViewModelToLoad;
            await _navigationService.NavigateToAsync(type);
        });

    }
```

Does anyone have any idea why this happens.

Comment: Can you show us the code where you are making changes in the UI?

Comment: Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => { IsBusy = true; }); IsBusy is a property that is binded from the view. It has the onpropertychanged event as well.                                                                                                                                           public bool IsBusy
        {
            get => _isBusy;
            set
            {
                _isBusy = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsBusy));
            }
        }

Comment: Were you able to see this issue on iOS and Android, on device and emulator? Also you said “ even though the command is executed” which command are you talking about?

Comment: @Saamer Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => { IsBusy = true; }); this is the command. I have tested on every platform both emulators and devices

Comment: Can you place some `Console.WriteLine` statements and check exactly what lines are called?

Comment: @Saamer I added a Console.WriteLine statement inside CrossGeolocator_Current_PositionChanged method and yes, it does execute even if i change page. However the problem updating the UI is still there